# Is there an area of graph theory that deals with searching for graphs that are optimal?

Tags: graph-theory

I will start with an example of a problem that is supposed to belong to the area I'm looking for.

> What tree with N nodes has the smallest sum of the distances between every two nodes?
>
> (Answer: a star where one node is connected to every other node, because 2 is the shortest possible distance between non-adjacent nodes.)

An important property of this problem is that the answer is a graph.

Question: is there an area of graph theory that deals with problems where the goal is to find the graph that is optimal according to the specified rules?

Comment: Yes, "extremal graph theory" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_graph_theory)

Comment: Extremal graph theory does seem very close, thanks. But all of the Wikipedia examples are looking at numerical properties instead of constructing an example and proving that it's optimal. Not sure if there's a difference.

Comment: It deals with finding graphs as well. Quoting from the link: "The Turán graph T(n,r) is an example of an extremal graph. It has the maximum possible number of edges for a graph on n vertices without (r + 1)-cliques."

Comment: Does it also cover problems where the number of vertices is not specified?

Comment: Also please post this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Sure. It encompasses questions such as (1) For a graph with given properties, what is the maximum/minimum value of ... (2) Classify/Find a graph $G$ with given properties such that ____ is as large/small as possible..

Comment: No time to post an answer right now. It's fine if someone else does.